# Power bi sum of a measure if the measure is greater than zero

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have calculated two measures:

```
MetalProduction = sum(IXMBalanceSheet[Metal_production])

MetalProductionLastYr = calculate([MetalProduction],dateadd('Date'[Date],-1,YEAR))
```

then calculated the difference between these measures for absolute change:

```
ABS Production Chg = [MetalProduction] - [MetalProductionLastYr]
```

Now while maintaining the filter context in power bi, I would like to sum the ABS Production chg where it is greater than zero.

How would this measure be compiled?

Answer (score 0):

Here some simply example:

```
GreaterThanZero =
CALCULATE (
    [ABS Production Chg],
    FILTER ( 'IXMBalanceSheet', VAR __temp = [ABS Production Chg] RETURN __temp > 0 )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi msta42a, thank you for your response. I tried your measure, strangely GreaterThanZero in my model returns the MetalProduction values (Prod in your model) that are greater than zero. Instead of returning the values of ABS Production chg. It might have to do with the ABS Production chg measure returning MetalProduction instead of the difference between MetalProduction and MetalProductionLastYr. I'm not sure why this is happening, any further insight would be helpful and I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: The following formula worked but now I want to aggregate the total for the values that are GreaterThanZero, any ideas on this would be helpful. YOY = 
    VAR CurrYear = 
     [MetalProduction]
    VAR PrevYear = 
     CALCULATE( 
      [MetalProduction],
      SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date])
     )
    VAR Result = 
     CurrYear - PrevYear
    RETURN Result.

Then I used, 
GreaterThanZero = if([YOY]>0,[YOY],0)

Comment: Im not sure what output do you want to achieve. Can you post examples of data and expected results in tabular form?